# Creating log based dashboard in Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver

We wrote a cloud function that emits logs. We want to create graph using this log. However, graph looks totally haywire. There are only `12 events` between between `2-3PM Nov 8th` but graph shows some constant `30` every `15min bucket` and some random numbers. Dashboard does not provide any way to take a dump of raw events used to plot the graph. Am I missing something? May be I need to set it up differently?

Attaching snapshots of raw events as well as graph.

**Raw Logs**
[image: raw logs]

**Stackdriver Graph for the same metric**
[image]

Comment: you dashboard display from 6 AM to 6 PM so with the 30 min interval (that you can set on the Alignment period) give 24 bar and counting these var are correct, how much log is within the bar according to the log count in your description they start at 14:18 and finish at 14:59 (count of 12 logs entry) , the bar are not synchronized to your logs entry as you saw in your dashboard the logs bar shown start at 14:48 and they will finish at the next bar start point, this is the count of logs. I don't know how to shown 30min interval and your Alignment period shows 15min something weird.

Comment: Try to count the log entry according to the starting point for the bar